# JavaScript Image not drawing to canvas

Tags: javascript

I am just being a complete noob and been looking around for a answer. "ctx.fillRect(0,0,100,100);" works which mean ctx was declared correctly and "test()" is being called. I just don't understand why the image wont draw.

```
var Img = new Image();
Img.scr ='/client/Assets/StartScreen/Background.png'; //This URL was tested via html img tag

function test(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,100,100);  //THIS WORKS
    ctx.drawImage(Img,0,0,600,600); // Will not load
}
```

Comment: maybe try './client/Assets/StartScreen/Background.png'

Comment: Trying it now. but using <img scr="/client/Assets/StartScreen/Background.png"> works in html

Comment: Nope Didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Img.scr ='/client/Assets/StartScreen/Background.png'; //This URL was tested via html img tag
```

**Img.scr** undefined property. You should try with **Img.src**

```
Img.src ='/client/Assets/StartScreen/Background.png';
```

Comment: I KNEW IT WOULD BE SOMETHING COMPLETELY DUMB!

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- Your code had `img.scr`, not `img.src`.
- Image loading happens asynchronously; you'll need to wait for the image to be complete (`img.complete`).  You can use the `onload` event listener to draw things the instant the image is ready.

---

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "/client/Assets/StartScreen/Background.png";

function draw() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 600, 600);
}

img.onload = function() {
  draw();
};
```

Comment: you just copy pasted the answer downvoting mine. You have good formatting though :D

Answer (score 0):

You should add image to canvas only when it is loaded.
try,

```
var Img = new Image();
Img.src ='/client/Assets/StartScreen/Background.png'; 
Img.onload = function() {
      test();
 }

function test(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,100,100);  
    ctx.drawImage(Img,0,0,600,600); 

}
```

Comment: This will cause strange behavior if other things are drawn after the image loads. It would be better to call all of `test()` only after the image has loaded.

Comment: This should be fine I guess if we call `test()` after image load